# How to add a new key and match a existing value in a dictionary of dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Below is the output which was obtained after a merge process.

> {
>
> u'a'{u'id'[u'VPH65848HI'],u'social_links'[‘linkedin_link’,’facebook_link’],
>
> u'b'{u'id'[u'VPH65848HJ'],u'social_links'[‘linkedin_link’,’facebook_link’]
>
> }

My desired output is

> {
>
> u'a': {u'id': [u'V-PH65848HI'], u'social_links': {‘linkedin’:[‘linkedin_link’],’facebook:[’facebook_link’]}},
>
> u'b': {u'id': [u'V-PH65848HJ'], u'social_links':
>   {‘linkedin’:[‘linkedin_link’],’facebook:[’facebook_link’]}}
>
> }

The below is the code:

```
for k,v in result.items():
    if v['social_links']:           
        for v1 in v['social_links']:
            if "facebook" in v1:
                result['facebook']=result['social_links'][1]
```

I don't know how to proceed with this. Kindly help ! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Would be nice to share your input as well...

Comment: @Julien:  I think the first blockquote is the input (the output from _some other_ process).

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be storing all the results.  So, I changed the type to a list with dictionaries inside it. Additionally, I looked over the code and made it so it doesn't rely in indexes when you already have a value loop to find `facebook`.

```
in1 = {

    u'a':{u'id':[u'VPH65848HI'],u'social_links':['linkedin_link','facebook_link']},

    u'b':{u'id':[u'VPH65848HJ'],u'social_links':['linkedin_link','facebook_link']}

    }

def isset(variable):
    return variable in locals() or variable in globals()

result = []
for k,v in in1.items():
    temp = {}
    for v1 in v[u'social_links'] :
        if "facebook" in v1:
            temp['facebook']=v1
    result.append(temp)
print(result)
```